# Redirect logged in user in Django

Tags: django, redirect

I need to redirect user if logged in to his home page when he goes to main url.
urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', LoginView.as_view(template_name='landing.html'), name='landing')
]
```

I tried creating custom view rather than using built in django login.

new urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', landing_validation, name='landing')
]
```

views.py

```
def landing_validation(request):
  if request.user.is_authenticated:
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/user/home')
  else:
    return login(request)
```

This works good when user is logged in and tries to enter landing page it redirects him to home page i.e when user tries http://127.0.0.1:8000 it redirects him to http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/home/. But when user logs out i get the error as follows
 `login() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'`

I have set urls in settings.py as follows but have never used them:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/user/home'

LOGIN_URL = '/'
```

Any insights on the issue are appreciated.

The logout is working perfectly fine and is as below.

Urls.py

```
  url(r'^logout/$',
      logoutUser,
    name='logout'
  ),
```

Views.py

```
def logoutUser(request):
  logout(request)
  return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Comment: `login` here appears to be the function from django.contrib.auth. As the docs - and the error - clearly show, this requires a `user` parameter, as in the user to log in. Where is that supposed to be coming from? Where is the form to allow the user to enter username and password?

Comment: The form is on the landing page itself and i haven't used any authentication to do so, i just used the default login view which seems to take care of the login authorization, but now that i need to redirect user on logout i don't know how to deal with the landing_validation view!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
urlpatterns = [ 
    url(r'^$', LoginView.as_view(template_name='landing.html', redirect_authenticated_user=True), name='landing')
```

]

Comment: No when user logs out he should go to landing page which is at 127.0.0.1:8000 and login is on that page itself, i need to redirect user to user/home if he is already logged in and trying to go to url 127.0.0.1:8000 and if he is not logged in he should go to that url itself to log in. The logout should lead him to landing page itself.

Comment: I have added the logout to the question which is working perfectly fine.

Comment: Just change the parameter "next_page=" like this: next_page='/', or you can use the reverse_lazy on urls.py like this:

from django.urls import path, reverse_lazy

path('logout/', LogoutView.as_view(
    next_page=reverse_lazy('the_name_of_you_url')
), name='logout'),

Comment: It is working the same with the change you suggested but i am not after logout, i need user to go his home page when he tries to go to main page/landing page. The logout doesn't seem to be the problem. I need to redirect user to his home page if he is already loggedin but if he hasn't logged out.

Comment: Oh my god, i've made a very bad mistake kk.
In my applications, i use the decorator "login_required" in all pages to redirect an unautenticated user to the login page, in login page i use this:

    path('login/', LoginView.as_view(
        template_name='login.html',
        redirect_authenticated_user=True
    ), name='login'),

To redirect users:

from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

path('', login_required(views.IndexView.as_view(), login_url=reverse_lazy('login')), name='index'),

Comment: Yes, this is in contrast to want i wanted, i want users to go to home page if he is logged in and wants to go to login/landing page. I don't know how but if user is unauthenticated they get reverted back to login page, i need the other way that if user is logged in he should go to home page if he goes to login page. I apologize if this is confusing !!

Comment: Like i've said, i think the redirect_authenticated_user=True using a LoginView in urls.py will be the answer to your question. Did you try?

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', LoginView.as_view(template_name='landing.html', redirect_authenticated_user=True), name='landing')
]

Comment: Yup , redirect_authenticated_user=True solved the issue. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

login function receives two positional arguments, you should wirte:

```
login(request, user)
```

See the docs for login here: [How to log a user in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in)

So you will need to get the user from the database in order to perform a login right there.

A simpler solution is to redirect to the login URL if the user is not authenticated.

Comment: This doesn't appear to have anything to do with the problem the OP is experiencing.

Comment: @DanielRoseman You was right, I miss read the question. Now is fine.

Comment: No, it isn't. If there is a `request.user`, then the user is already logged in.

Comment: @RaydelMiranda I am not using user for validation, I was using built-in LoginView but now that i had to use cutom login, i am kind of stuck on what to do if user is not logged in or when user logs out.